# Ribbis concern regarding bonus on sales

Tags: halacha, money, lending-interest-ribbis

RIBBIS QUESTION:

In a travel agents' office, where the pay is based on a base + commission + bonus system, and a bonus is given to any agent who sells more than a certain weekly sales quota, may an agent who is just slightly short of the bonus amount toward the end of a week ask another agent to forward a customer to him, in exchange for forwarding one of his own customers to that agent the following week. Do we need to be concerned that the sale which will be "repaid" to the first forwarding agent will be more valuable than the sale originally given.

If this is a concern, how do we figure the value of each sale made? Do we look at the dollar value, and if the returned sale is of higher dollar value than the originally forwarded sale, it would be considered ribbis, or would we say that since the original sale put the accepting agent into the bonus area, by putting him over the weekly sales quote, we include the bonus value into the value of the first sale, and there won't be a ribbis problem unless the second sale is of higher value than the bonus earned by the original accepting agent?

Comment: Glengarry Glen Ross was just on a few days ago--this question brought to mind the setting of that movie...but it was a different situation..

Comment: @Gary So what did the chief Rabbi of Hollywood rule on the Glen Ross question? **:)**

Comment: Re "If this is a concern, how do we figure the value of each sale made?": if it's a concern, it sounds like a concern of סאה בסאה, which is a concern no matter how you figure the value.

Comment: I don't know how the Chief Rabbi ruled, but Al Pacino sure was intent on getting his Cadillac from Kevin Spacey for winning the contest:"who told you you could work with men?"etc,...good stuff, w Jack Lemmon(with his famous line to Spacey "You ARE a s-head"), Alan Arkin, all of them trying to use "old fashioned hard-sell techniques" to sell patches of sketchy land developments to folks.

Comment: Did anybody call it a "loan"? **But it is sure at least an הונאה of the employer if not גזל ממש.** He's factually "stealing" the bonus he didn't deserve - what would you say if **all the employees** unite and level all the clients off?

Comment: @AlBerko 1- There are many instances when things which don't may not look like a loan yet are halachically considered a loan. Usually when one gives something to someone else with agreement to receive return at a later time, it can be considered a loan. 2- The employer doesn't mind when the accepting employee is just slightly short of the bonus margin. He's a nice guy! 3- I didn't understand the addition about the employess uniting. You may explain if you care to.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore I meant (maybe I phrased it bad) that this is a sort of Midas Sdom, when something bad can be only tested in a way that **"if everybody would do it - what then"**? So you can claim the employer doesn't care for one or two, but if all the employees adopt the practice, they all will be fired, I think.

Comment: The (Kabbalic) base for Ribbis is that כסף is called דמים as you know and paying the extra part of soul causes a mess in the Heavenly Accounting unit. Other, non monetary cases are "educational" only to habituate good practices. For a case to "count" as כסף one must own a thing. In your question a salesperson does not "own" the customer, therefore it does not count as Ribbis.

Comment: @AlBerko He does own the RIGHTS to that particular account, if it was presented to him first. If he gives it away with a requirement to receive another in return it could be a loan.

Comment: Great! Maybe you're right. Can one Mekadesh a woman with that right?

Comment: @AlBerko Maybe.